# How can solr highlighting recognize html tags?

Tags: html, solr, tags, highlight

I have a question about Solr highlighting. 
When you use the highlighting function with the methods, "setHighlightSimplePre" and "setHighlightSimplePost", and set some html tag, you would get a highlighted term that is surrounded by the html tags. 
For example, when you query with "test", and set "<b>" as the argument for setHighlightSimplePre and "</b>" as the argument for setHighlightSimplePost, you would get "<b>test</b>" as string form as long as at least a field has the value "test". 
Here is a thing. If a field has a value like "testA <b>testB test", you would get "testA <b>testB <b>test</b>", meaning you will see "testA **testB <b>test**" if you output the result as html. 
How can I solve this problem? That is, in this example, I want to output the result like "testA <b>testB **test**". 
is there any way to recognize html tags before highlighting?

Comment: Of course, in this example, I can avoid this problem by using any other tag instread of <b></b> for the argument, but that's not an essential solution because a field may have other kinds of tags.

Answer (score 0):

you could strip the html from the content before highlighting.

or you can use a highliter class instead of <b>, like

```
setHighlightSimplePre('<span class="hilite">');

setHighlightSimplePost('</span>');
```

then override the style of the surrounding content:

```
div.content b {font-weight: normal;}
```

and set the style of highlited text:

```
.hilite {font-weight: bold; color: yellow;}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm beginner so it's not completely clear for me.
So you mean what I basically need to do is to use <span> tag and to define a class in which I define what I want to do for highlighting?

Comment: However I think the problem still remains.
If a field has a value "testA <span class="anyOtherClass">testB test", the resulf will be "testA <span class="anyOtherClass">testB <span class="hilite">test</span>", which means this is the same problem as I wrote.